# REST API on iMIS

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest

I'm using iMIS, a cloud-based Customer Relation Management(CRM), at my work and want to connect the database with PowerBI. In order to do this, I want to use REST API. However, my jQuery seems not working on my end. I use my own verification token that I got from Chrome's developer page? (the page that I can access to when I type <kbd>f12</kbd> on my Windows computer) I'm using the below code chunk provided by their website. I've been going back and forth between ChatGPT, Bard, and their documentation, but my effort has been fertile so far.

I'd appreciate any help!

Documentation link: https://developer.imis.com/reference/api-1

```
jQuery.ajax("https://testapi.imis.com/sdkdemo/api/party/101", {
  type: "GET",
  contentType: "application/json",
  headers: {
    RequestVerificationToken: document.getElementById(
      "__RequestVerificationToken"
    ).value
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

I'm using the code below.

For the URL, I use the verification token but it hasn't worked thus far. Which URL should I use?

```
jQuery.ajax("https://testapi.imis.com/sdkdemo/api/party/101", {
  type: "GET",
  contentType: "application/json",
  headers: {
    RequestVerificationToken: document.getElementById(
      "__RequestVerificationToken"
    ).value
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```